# pass unicode parameter to Java command line

Tags: java, unicode, java-8

Using JDK 1.8 and on OSX. For `args`, one of them is unicode (Chinese, Japanese, etc.) characters. Wondering how to pass them? I searched a few solution on SO, but not working.

I have tried,

1. add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` when execute java command to run the class file;
2. passing unicode parameter by quote of `` and quote of "".

In my code, I tried to print `args.length` at the beginning of `main`, it is always print out zero.

regards,
Lin

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Set your `LANG` environment variable to use UTF-8 encoding. For example, if your language is US English, your LANG environment variable could be `en_US.UTF-8` to signal a US English locale with UTF-8 encoding. Use the following command to set the LANG variable:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Should you want to make this permanent for your user, add it to your `~/.profile` file, so that it takes effect upon every login for that user. Use the `locale -a` command to find out all available locales on your system.

Comment: Thanks, and how to pass unicode parameter, by using `''` or `""`?

Comment: BTW, it seems I already using `en_US.UTF-8`, see output, `echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Enclosing an argument within quotes are used to specify arguments containing whitespace characters to be considered as single arguments instead of multiple. Single quotes are used instead of double quotes when you want to suppress shell expansion.

Comment: In my case, the unicode string as input command line parameter contains space, so I should use double quotes?

Comment: You could use both single and double quotes, but use single quotes if you want to suppress shell expansion. See the output of the command `echo "$LANG" '$LANG'` for an example.

Comment: Also check your terminal settings, not sure if it should be autodetecting the character encoding from the environment variables or not. Make sure it's [set to UTF-8 in the settings dialog](http://i.imgur.com/IGy28hd.png).

Comment: I think my terminal setting is fine, since I can use rm command to delete a file with unicode file name. Do you have a simple example in Java, which could accept command line unicode UTF-8 input in `args`?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work with java the same way as it works with every other command. Might be something specific to your environment.

Comment: Thanks Nándor Előd Fekete, do you have a working simple sample at your hand? I can try if my environment issues.