# Passing unicode string to java from windows command promot

Tags: java, unicode, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need to pass a file path to main method from windows command line.

```
c:\scanner> java -jar scanner.jar path-to-file-with-unicode-characters
```

The file path contains a unicode characters and those characters are being removed/replaced after being passed to java main

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660651/passing-command-line-unicode-argument-to-java-code.  As old as that question and most of its answers are, I don’t think the situation has changed.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate: pass unicode parameter to Java command line] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937997/pass-unicode-parameter-to-java-command-line)

Comment: @RafaelPalomino Dealing with Unicode in Windows is quite different from dealing with it in Unix and Linux, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the command line and its encoding.

The solution might be to store the file path is a separate small text file.

Under Linux the convention for this is to prefix with a `@`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
        if (args[i].startsWith("@")) {
            Path path = Paths.get(args[i].substring(1));
            args[i] = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();
        }
    }
    RealClass.main(args);
}
```